# Keep receiving the error "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL"

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, maven, spring-jdbc

I am using springboot, maven and postgresql JDBC to create a simple movie api but whenever i make a http GET request this error keeps showing up:

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select m1_0.imdb_id,m1_0.backdrops,m1_0.genres,m1_0.poster,m1_0.release_date,m1_0.title,m1_0.trailer_link from movies m1_0] [ERROR: column m1_0.imdb_id does not exist\n  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column \"m1_0.imdbid\".\n  Position: 8] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:277)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:335)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:249)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy116.findAll(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.br.Idespair.MoviesAPIWithSQL.service.MovieService.AllMovies(MovieService.java:18)\r\n\tat com.br.Idespair.MoviesAPIWithSQL.controller.MovieController.getAllMovies(MovieController.java:25)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:262)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select m1_0.imdb_id,m1_0.backdrops,m1_0.genres,m1_0.poster,m1_0.release_date,m1_0.title,m1_0.trailer_link from movies m1_0] [ERROR: column m1_0.imdb_id does not exist\n  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column \"m1_0.imdbid\".\n  Position: 8] [n/a]\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:91)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:58)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:265)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:167)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:218)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:98)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:19)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:66)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:203)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:209)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:83)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:76)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:65)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$2(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:137)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:359)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:300)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:509)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:427)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:120)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:383)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:352)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\r\n\t... 59 more\r\nCaused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column m1_0.imdb_id does not exist\n  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column \"m1_0.imdbid\".\n  Position: 8\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2401)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:368)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:498)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:415)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:134)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:246)\r\n\t... 99 more\r\n",
    "message": "JDBC exception executing SQL [select m1_0.imdb_id,m1_0.backdrops,m1_0.genres,m1_0.poster,m1_0.release_date,m1_0.title,m1_0.trailer_link from movies m1_0] [ERROR: column m1_0.imdb_id does not exist\n  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column \"m1_0.imdbid\".\n  Position: 8] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]",
    "path": "/api/movies"
}
```

And i cant figure out why

My controller class:

```
package com.br.Idespair.MoviesAPIWithSQL.controller;

import com.br.Idespair.MoviesAPIWithSQL.model.Movie;
import com.br.Idespair.MoviesAPIWithSQL.service.MovieService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/movies")
public class MovieController {

@Autowired
private MovieService movieService;

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> getAllMovies(){
return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> 
(movieService.AllMovies(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
@GetMapping("/{imdbId}")
public ResponseEntity<Optional<Movie>> 
getSingleMovie(@PathVariable 
String imdbId){
return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Movie>> 
(movieService.singleMovie(imdbId),HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

My Service Class:

```
package com.br.Idespair.MoviesAPIWithSQL.service;

import com.br.Idespair.MoviesAPIWithSQL.model.Movie;
import 
com.br.Idespair.MoviesAPIWithSQL.repository.IMovieRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class MovieService {

@Autowired
private IMovieRepository movieRepository;

public List<Movie> AllMovies(){
return movieRepository.findAll();
}

public Optional<Movie> singleMovie(String imdbId){
return movieRepository.findMovieByImdbId(imdbId);
}

}
```

My model class where i created the movie instance:

```
package com.br.Idespair.MoviesAPIWithSQL.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Reference;


import java.util.List;
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "movies")
public class Movie {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String imdbId;
private String title;
private String releaseDate;
private String trailerLink;
private String poster;
private List<String> genres;
private List<String> backdrops;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie")
private List<Review> reviews;

public Movie(String imdbId, String title, String 
releaseDate, String trailerLink, String poster, List<String> 
genres, List<String> backdrops) {
                this.imdbId = imdbId;
                this.title = title;
                this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
                this.trailerLink = trailerLink;
                this.poster = poster;
                this.genres = genres;
                this.backdrops = backdrops;
        }
}
```

And my repository class:

```
package com.br.Idespair.MoviesAPIWithSQL.repository;

import com.br.Idespair.MoviesAPIWithSQL.model.Movie;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


public interface IMovieRepository extends 
JpaRepository<Movie,String> {

    Optional<Movie> findMovieByImdbId(String imdbId);

}
```

I've tried to read the error message and it say there's an error with object imdb_id and that it should be imdbId, but all the objects that refers to imdbId are written this way and theres no imdb_id written on any of my classes.

I'm using postman for the HTTP request and postgres for the database
I havent used docker on this application.

Comment: Consider reviewing this documentation on naming strategies:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.configure-hibernate-naming-strategy

Comment: It looks like the column in the database is actually `imdbid` instead of `imdb_id`. Please verify it and show us the table schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message mentions that the column "m1_0.imdb_id" does not exist, I think that the error occurs because there is a mismatch between the field name (`imdbId`) in your Java code and the corresponding column name (`imdb_id`) in your database. You can try to add the following line to fix this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "imdb_id") // Add this line
private String imdbId;
```

By adding `@Column(name="imdb_id")` to your Java code, you're saying to Spring Boot, when he saves or retrieves the field `imdbId` in the database, use the column named `imdb_id`.

If this suggestion solve your problem, maybe you need to do the same process for all the fields written in **camelCase**.

**Edit:** Also you can see https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-field-naming-spring-boot